# Spivak, Ch. 23, "Infinite Series", Problem 23: Prove if $\{a_n\}$ decreasing, summable then $\{2^n a_{2^n}\}$ summable. (Cauchy Condensation Theorem)

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

The following is a problem from chapter 23 "Infinite Series" from Spivak's *Calculus*

> *23. Suppose $\{a_n\}$ is decreasing and $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n=0$. Prove that if $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges, then
> $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty 2^n a_{2^n}$ also converges (the "Cauchy
> Condensation Theorem"). Notice that the divergence of
> $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}$ is a special case, for if
> $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}$ converged, then
> $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty 2^n\frac{1}{2^n}$ would also converge; this
> remark may serve as a hint.

I obtained a solution and then checked the solution manual. The latter has an elegant solution, but it differs from the solution I came up with. My question is if the solution below is correct?

Assume $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges.

Then $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_{2^n}$ converges.

Let's apply the ratio test to $\{2^na_{2^n}\}$.

$$\frac{2^{n+1}a_{2^{n+1}}}{2^na_{2^n}}=2\cdot\frac{a_{2^{n+1}}}{a_{2^n}}$$

$$=2\cdot\frac{a_{2^{n+1}-1}}{a_{2^n}}\frac{a_{2^{n+1}}}{a_{2^{n+1}-1}}$$

$$=2\cdot \frac{a_{2^{n+1}-2}}{a_{2^n}}\frac{a_{2^{n+1}-1}}{a_{2^{n+1}-2}}\frac{a_{2^{n+1}}}{a_{2^{n+1}-1}}$$

$$=(...)$$

$$=2\cdot \frac{a_{2^n+1}}{a_{2^n}}\frac{a_{2^n+2}}{a_{2^n+1}}...\frac{a_{2^{n+1}-1}}{a_{2^{n+1}-2}}\frac{a_{2^{n+1}}}{a_{2^{n+1}-1}}\tag{1}$$

Claim: $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}<1$

Proof: $\{a_n\}$ is summable, hence $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_n=0$. But $\{a_n\}$ is decreasing, so it must be the case that $a_n>0$ (otherwise the terms $a_n$ would not approach $0$).

Thus, in (1), each fraction equals some $0<r<1$. Then

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{2^{n+1}a_{2^{n+1}}}{2^na_{2^n}}=2r^\infty=0\tag{2}$$

By the ratio test, $\{2^na_{2^n}\}$ is summable.

Is this proof correct, and in particular, is the calculation of the limit in (2) technically correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not, because your $r$'s depend on n. An infinite product of positive terms $<1$ is not necessarily $0.$ Think of [the product $\prod_{n=2}^\infty\left(1-\frac1{n^2}\right)=\frac12.$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series#Telescoping_product)

Comment: In the product you mention, if we consider it a product of terms of a sequence, the sequence terms converge to 1. If these terms represent $\alpha=a_{n+1}/a_{n}$ then $\{a_n\}$ does not converge by the ratio test. In the case of the question, can we not make the following argument: $\beta=\sup\{\alpha\}$ must be $<1$. If it were not, then there would be a subsequence with $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_{n+1}/a_n=1$, and this subsequence would thus not be summable. Thus $\{a_n\}$ would not be summable (since all terms are positive). Now, an infinite product of $\beta$ is zero, no?

Comment: "If these terms represent $α=a_{n+1}/a_n$ then this sequence does not converge by the ratio test": no, it is an inconclusive cas of the ratio test. "there would be a subsequence with $\lim_{n→∞}a_{n+1}/a_n=1,$ and this subsequence would thus not be summable": no, $\lim_{k→∞}a_{n_k+1}/a_{n_k}=1$ does not imply $\lim_{k→∞}a_{n_{k+1}}/a_{n_k}=1.$